# repo.save not storing data in H2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, debugging, spring-data-jpa, h2

`I have created simple spring project where I am using requestmapping to store data in my H2 database. I am getting parameters in URL but data is getting saved.

I am new in spring boot and facing this issue. Please help me with this. Thanks

//Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class TrialTwoController {
    
    @Autowired
    Repository repos;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.jsp";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(path="/addUser")
    public TrailTwo post(@RequestBody TrailTwo trail) {
        repos.save(trail);
        return trail;
    }   
}

//Model class

@Entity
public class TrailTwo {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}

Repository Interface

public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<TrailTwo, Integer> {

}

application properties
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:anshul
```

[image: localhost URL]

[image: Class Structure]
`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller, you want to return TrailTwo entity. However, because you use @Controller and not `@RestController`, Spring won't be able to return the entity and will try to render the view instead which will result in the exception.

In order to fix this problem, you need to add `@ResponseBody` for in your method.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/addUser")
public @ResponseBody TrailTwo post(@RequestBody TrailTwo trail) {
    repos.save(trail);
    return trail;
}
```

You can also separate the concerns and have UserController which will be annotated with `@RestController` and ViewController which will be annotated with `@Controller`. This way, you won't have to add `@ResponseBody` annotation inside `@RestController`.

On another note, make sure to use POST http method for adding new entities. Instead of using `@RequestMapping`, you can use `@PostMapping` which will limit the supported http methods to POST. For POST, parameters need to be passed as a part of request body.

Make sure you understand http methods and how to use them to build robust REST apis. It will make your life easier. You can read about different http methods and how to use them here https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

For the full working example, you can take a look here: https://github.com/CaptainAye/repository-h2-sample

Comment: Hey, I tried both the way, Adding @Responsebody and cloning your project but nothing worked. I made a few changes:

Added home page request and created a JSP page that contains a simple form. From the form, I am trying to send a post request but the data is not getting saved.

Comment: How do you verify that the data is not added to the database? Do you get any exception?

Comment: After clicking on submit, I am getting data in the URL(http://localhost:8080/addUser?id=101&name=Anshul) and on the UI I am getting a Whitelabel error page. Also, I have an h2 database, So the table is getting created but there is no data in the table.

Comment: If you get whitelabel error, there should be an exception thrown as well. Please, provide the exception.

Comment: I am getting this: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]

Comment: It started working for me and data is getting stored now. I changed the HTTP method to this @RequestMapping(path="/addUser", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })

Comment: it's a good practice to use dedicated annotation instead of RequestMapping - GetMapping or PostMapping, depending on which one you'd like to implement. Also remember to use POST for creating data, not GET